# Server requites chkdsk after every power cycle

Tags: boot, windows-server-2008-r2, chkdsk

I've discovered that after every shutdown, Windows Server 2008 R2 will automatically go to the system recovery, and I have to run `chkdsk /r` and let it complete. Then after the reboot, it will boot that once into Windows, then require me to do the entire process again every power cycle.

BUT: it finds no errors and says that the disk is fine.

Is this then a corrupted installation or faulty hard drive??

AND: does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server always require a checkdisk, it probably means some faulty hardware (or drivers).

You should verify the SMART data of your hard drives (Eurosoft PC-Check or Fedora/Ubuntu live cd will have disk utilities).

Comment: Yupp, that confirms it, the checker on the Ubuntu live CD says at least 5 bad sectors - looks like a warrenty replacement is in order, esp. with the current price of HDDs

Thanks for helping me confirm this XD